# True or False:Let $X$ be a topological space such that any two nonempty openset in $X$ intersect, then $X$ is compact.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space such that  any two nonempty open sets in $X$  intersect,then  $X$ is compact. True /false
?

I  don't know how to think about this  problem.

Any hints/solution ?

Comment: False, consider the topology over $\mathbb{N}$ generated by $\{\{1,k\}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: @PoonLevi Why not an official answer?

Answer (score 3):

The statement is false. Consider the topology over $\mathbb{N}$ generated by $\{\{1, k\}: k\in\mathbb{N}\}$.